# Initialize a variable with the value of a screen field

Tags: excel, vba, copy, sap-gui

I've got a script going through `MM03` transaction. There are 2 screen fields Period (Month) and Year that I want to copy into variables.

There is no chance to do this with export or print, because it is a not changeable box.

I tried to record using SAP GUI Recorder, I click in a field box and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it isn't recorded, so I have to do this part with VBA. I tried it like this, but it doesn't fit.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public SapGuiAuto
Public objGui As GuiApplication
Public objConn As GuiConnection
Public session As GuiSession
    
Sub SAPCustomerReport()
    
    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set objGui = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    Set objConn = objGui.Children(0)
    Set session = objConn.Children(0)
    
    Dim DataObj As New DataObject
    Dim month As String
    Dim year As String
    
    Application.OnKey "^A", ""
    Application.OnKey "^C", ""
    
    session.FindById("wnd[0]").Maximize
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "TransactionExample"
    session.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-MATNR").Text = "MaterialExample"
    session.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP27").Select
    session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-WERKS").Text = "PlaceExample"
    session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP27/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB2:SAPLMGD1:2953/txtMBEW-PPRDL").SetFocus
    
    
      SendKeys "^A"
      SendKeys "^C"
      DataObj.GetFromClipboard
      month = DataObj.GetText
    
    Set SapGuiAuto = Nothing
    Set objGui = Nothing
    Set objConn = Nothing
    Set session = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: If it is a [textfield](https://help.sap.com/docs/sap_gui_for_windows/b47d018c3b9b45e897faf66a6c0885a8/a9af75bc7d08499ca19ec3879db7d7b3.html?version=760.03&locale=en-US) you can very likely read it with the text property.

Comment: No it is just a field which shows a number. i cannot edit the field, and i cannot export it. thats why i want to mark copy and paste into variable

Comment: Anyway, it should be a GuiVComponent object which has a text property. If you see a text then the text property should return that text.

Comment: It's not working like u saying.

Comment: What did you try? Right now I do not see any reference to that field in your code.

Comment: with [...].SetFocus I activate the cell
I can only get the data out of there, if i press manual strg + a, strg + c. 
There is no other way.
But if I try it with the way out of SAP with OnKey and SendKey, it doens't work.
And if  I go like .SendVKey 72 and .SendVKey 77 in SAP directly it's also not working.

Comment: Ok, I see. You do not have any clue how to reference the field.  You need to use FindById to get that field and then you can get at the text. Recording will not get you there. You have to give more information on the transaction and which field you are after.

Comment: its Transaction MM03
Kalkulation 2 and i want to get the Periode (Month) and the Year of the running kalkulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code the following code will retrieve the month and year of the current period in the tab Costing2

```
Option Explicit

Public SapGuiAuto
Public objGui As GuiApplication
Public objConn As GuiConnection
Public session As GuiSession

Sub SAPCustomerReport()

    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set objGui = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    Set objConn = objGui.Children(0)
    Set session = objConn.Children(0)

    Dim month As String
    Dim year As String

    session.FindById("wnd[0]").Maximize
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nMM03"
    session.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-MATNR").Text = "xxxxx"
    session.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
    session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP27").Select
    session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-WERKS").Text = "xxxx"
    session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press
    
    month = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP27/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB2:SAPLMGD1:2951/txtMBEW-PPRDL").Text
    year = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP27/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB2:SAPLMGD1:2951/txtMBEW-PDATL").Text

End Sub
```

The question is how to get at the IDs of the screen elements in question in order to use `findByID` for retrieving the field content. I usually take the Tracker

Tracker: [Homepage](https://tracker.stschnell.de/) [Blog entry](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/11/20/scripting-tracker-development-tool-for-sap-gui-scripting/)

SAPGUI [Scripting Documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/sap_gui_for_windows/b47d018c3b9b45e897faf66a6c0885a8/babdf65f4d0a4bd8b40f5ff132cb12fa.html?version=760.03&locale=en-US)

A nicer resp. more readable version might look like that

```
Option Explicit

Public SapGuiAuto
Public objGui As GuiApplication
Public objConn As GuiConnection
Public session As GuiSession

Sub SAPCustomerReport()

    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set objGui = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    Set objConn = objGui.Children(0)
    Set session = objConn.Children(0)

    Dim month As String
    Dim year As String

    With session
    
        .FindById("wnd[0]").Maximize
        .FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nMM03"
        .FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
        .FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-MATNR").Text = "xxxxxx"
        .FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
        .FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP27").Select
        .FindById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-WERKS").Text = "xxxx"
        .FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press
        
        Dim guiArea As GuiVComponent
        Set guiArea = .FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP27/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB2:SAPLMGD1:2951")
        
    End With
    
    With guiArea
        month = .FindById("txtMBEW-PPRDL").Text
        year = .FindById("txtMBEW-PDATL").Text
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thats perfectly working. Thx. I tried this option before but with recorder there was no difference between both boxes. so the "PPRDL" and "PDATL". It had shown in both activatings the same code. 
So thx a lot!